# Endomorphism simple with parameter k

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I came accross an exercise that reads as follows:

> What are the values of the parameter *k* such that the following
>   endomorphism is simple.

Here's the matrix associated with the endomorphism:

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & k \\
    -10 & 0 & 1 \\
    10 & 0 & 3 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

So I went ahead and solved it, only to come up with the wrong solution.
Here are my steps:

**1)** Find the characteristic polynomial

$-λ (λ^2 - 4 λ - 10 k + 3)$

**2)** Check if there are *n* distinct eigenvalues, so *n* distinct roots, with *n = 3* in this case with our 3x3 matrix. Clearly the first is $λ = 0$.

**3)** Notice that $(λ^2 - 4 λ - 10 k + 3) = 0$  has 2 solutions when $\Delta > 0$.

**4)** $\Delta = \sqrt{10k-x}$  so $\sqrt{10k-x} > 0$ therefore $k > -\frac{1}{10}$

**5)** Notice that the polynomial also goes to $0$ for $(λ^2 - 4 λ - 10 k + 3) = 0 $ when $k = \frac{1}{10}(\lambda^2-4\lambda+3) $ .

So now my final solution would be to say, as a condition for the endomorphism being simple,

$k \not= \frac{1}{10}(\lambda^2-4\lambda+3) $ AND $k > -\frac{1}{10}$

However, my book says that the actual solution is just $k > -\frac{1}{10}$ .
What am I doing wrong?

Edit: So as it turns out, I wasn't doing anything wrong, the book was. Marking the first answer as solved as it confirms of my own solution.

Comment: What is your definition of a simple endomorphism?

Comment: @Jan An endomorphism F:V -> V is simple if there exists  a basis of V made from eigenvectors of F. Practically, it is simple if the associated matrix is diagonalizable. This is what I was taught, English isn't my first language, sorry if I'm using any term with the wrong translation.

Comment: I came to this question wondering if there was a notion of simple endomorphism in analogy to semi-simple ones, which I expected to be something like: there is no invariant subspaces except for $\{0\}$ and the wholse space (I guess for non algebraically closed field e.g. $\mathbb{R}$ it's just $2\times 2 $ rotations...). But here it seems that the "simplicity" refers to the multiplicity of the factors in the characteristic polynomial, which have to be 1... (So, more than in the actual def. of Athams, it's diagonalizable with different eigenvalues). If it is the minimal polynomial which would be

Comment: square free, then it is in this case really equivalent to the notion of semi-simplicity: for any stable subspace there exist a stable supplementary, which in algebraically closed field is being diagonalizable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to solve the polynomial for $\lambda$, not for $k$.

Call your matrix $A$. The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is

$$\chi_A(\lambda) = - \lambda \cdot ( (1 - \lambda)(3 - \lambda) - 10k).$$

One root is $0$ and the other two roots are $\lambda = 2 \pm \sqrt{1 + 10k}$.

If $1 + 10k < 0$, then there are two complex conjugate eigenvalues, hence the matrix is not diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $k = - 1/10$. In this case, the eigenvalue $2$ has multiplicity $2$, but one can easily check that the corresponding eigenspace has dimension $1$. Hence, $A$ is not diagonalizable for $k = - 1/10$.

Suppose $k = 3/10$. Then the eigenvalues are $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = 0$ and $\lambda_3 = 4$. But the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda_1$ is only one-dimensional, hence $A$ is not diagonalizable.

Finally, let $k \in (-1/10, \infty) \setminus \{3 / 10\}$. Then the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda_1 = 0$, and $\lambda_2 = 2 + \sqrt{1 + 10k} \neq 2 - \sqrt{1 + 10k} = \lambda_3$ with $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$ and $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_3$, hence all three eigenvalues are distinct. For every such $k$ the matrix $A$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: What I don't understand is why we aren't solving for k too. If $k=(1/10)(λ^2−4λ+3)$ , the characteristic polynomial would always be 0, so the matrix wouldn't be diagonalizable, right? Take for example the 3x3 matrix of rows: {2,k,1}, {0,0,0}, {k,0,1}. Same exercise, and this time the book says k != 2 and k != -(1/4) as a solution. So this time it's solving for k and for lambda.

Comment: Because $k$ is a "fixed constant". You are looking at the matrix for each possible value of $k$, i. e., you consider infinitely many matrices. You have to imagine that you know $k$ from the beginning, but leave it as a variable since you want to cover more cases at once.

Comment: So basically if the polynomial goes to 0 depending on a value of k, if k depends on λ (like in k=(1/10)(λ^2−4λ+3)), then that condition isn't included in the solution becaue k should be a fixed constant? And that's why in the second exercise the value of k that makes the polynomial go to 0 is included: it is a fixed value, independent of λ. Is this correct?

Comment: @Athamas This is correct.

Comment: Thank you for the explaination, the issue is, that I can't reconcile theory with practice. Following my own intuition, we find for example that for k = 3/10, the alg. multiplicity of the eigenvalue 0 is 2, while the eigenspace has dimension 1. 3/10 is in the interval k > -1/10, so k > -1/10 cannot be sufficinet. What am I doing wrong? It appears that k≠1/10(λ^2−4λ+3) holds for λ=0, and λ=0 as an eigenvalue is fixed and independend of k.

Comment: @Athamas I understand your problem. The answer given in your book is wrong and mine too, I will edit it.